# Javascript Fade-in Text on mouse-over

Tags: javascript, html, css

someone already has already posted the solution to my question, seen below. I want the same effect but only for certain parts of the page rather than all of the content. I basically only want certain parts of the page to fade in when the mouse is moved.

```
// attach event handler
document.body.onmousemove = function(){
  fadeIn( this, 1000 );      // 1000ms -> 1s
  this.onmousemove = null; // remove to only fade in once!
};

// sets the opacity of an element (x-browser)
function setOpacity( obj, value ) {
  if ( obj ) {
    obj.style.opacity = value / 100;
    obj.style.filter  = 'alpha(opacity=' + value + ')';
    obj.style.zoom    = 1;
  }
}

// makes an element to fade in
function fadeIn( dom, interval, delay ) {

      interval  = interval || 1000;
      delay     = delay    || 10;

  var opacity   = 0,
      start     = Number(new Date()),
      op_per_ms =  100 / interval;

  if ( typeof dom === "string" ) {
    dom = document.getElementById( dom );
  }

  function step() {

    var now     = Number(new Date()),
        elapsed = now - start;
        opacity = elapsed * op_per_ms;

    setOpacity( dom, opacity );

    if ( elapsed < interval )
      setTimeout( step, delay );
    else
      setOpacity( dom, 100 );
  }

  setTimeout( step, delay );
};
```

Comment: This very much seems like a "give the codez plz" question.  At the very least, please use the formatting features to make the code readable.

Comment: I'm not looking for code... the code is already there. If at least I could comment on the the question I got it from I wouldn't need to post a whole new one. And I did use the formatting features but for whatever reason they didn't work.

Comment: So, if you have the code, what's the issue?

Comment: I embedded the code in one of my pages but it fades in all div's and text. I only want certain parts of the page faded in. Here's the code in action: http://jsbin.com/ituwa3/7/edit . Just putting me in the right path would be a big help.

Comment: *"someone already has already posted the solution"*.. It's my baby... :) And so cute :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `fadeIn(this, 1000);`

- Assign a class `fade` to the elements you want to fade.
- Add style attribute `style="opacity: 0;"` to those elements instead of the `body` element.
- Get the elements you want to fade

  ```
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('fade');
  ```
- Iterate through the elements fading each one

  ```
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length(); i++) {
      fadeIn(elements[i], 1000);
  }
  ```

Here's a modified [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ituwa3/25/edit).

Comment: It should be `document.getElementsByClassName()`, but I would hesitate on using this, since only the newest browsers support it. I am also not sure the OP would want to null the onmousemove of all those elements. Otherwise, this method will work.

Comment: There are lots of cross-browser implementations of this method available, one is http://robertnyman.com/2005/11/07/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname/.

Comment: @melhosseiny: That's absolutely right. I should have made my comment more clear. It was meant to caution the OP to use those cross-browser implementations if he or she uses this method.

Comment: Thank you TNi and melhosseiny!

Comment: @mellowfellow Use this to get it work cross-browser: http://www.dustindiaz.com/getelementsbyclass/

Answer (score 0):

This is not very difficult using the well-commented code you already have. All you need is to replace the `fadeIn()` call with more appropriate calls. Pass in either the ID of an element you want to fade or the element itself into the first argument. You can do this for many elements just by calling `fadeIn()` many times. The animation should occur simultaneously.

**Update:** In the OP's case, he or she will need to remove the 0 opacity style on the body tag in order for these changes to work.

Comment: This should basically be it.  However, it's not working on jsbin. =/

Comment: The OP will need to remove the 0 opacity style on body as well. Updated answer to reflect this. Edit: Also, the originally faded out elements should have opacity 0 added in.

Comment: OIC, I should've noticed that.  /headdesk